# Celery broadcast vs RabbitMQ fanout

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I've been working with Celery lately and I don't like it. It's configuration is messy, overcomplicated and poorly documented.

I want to send broadcast messages with Celery from a single producer to multiple consumers. What confuses me is discrepancy between Celery terms and terms of underlying transport RabbitMQ.

In RabbitMQ you can have a single [fanout Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) and multiple Queues to broadcast messages:

[image]

But in Celery the terms are all messed up: here you can have a [broadcast Queue](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#broadcast), which sends messages to multiple consumers:

[image]

I don't even understand, how Celery broadcast queue is supposed to work at all, cause RabbitMQ queues with multiple consumers are meant for load balancing. So in RabbitMQ if multiple consumers (i.e. a pool of consumers) are connected to the same queue, only one consumer will receive and process message, [which is called round robin in RabbitMQ docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html).

Also, Celery documentation on broadcast is really insufficient. What type of RabbitMQ exchange should I specify for Broadcast queue, fanout or not? Could you supply a full example?

So, what I'm asking for is (1) clarification of concept and implementation of Broadcast queues in Celery and (2) a complete example of Broadcast queues configuration. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#exchanges-queues-and-routing-keys It appears the 'queue' definition in Celery includes the exchange, so possibly you can define a Celery queue on top of a fanout exchange which will have an underlying implementation of multiple RabbitMQ queues.  In this case I would guess you don't want a 'broadcast' queue in the Celery config, unless you really want multiple workers processing the same task

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for reply, I've been using that page extensively, but as you can see, the definition of Broadcast queue there is `CELERY_QUEUES = (Broadcast('broadcast_tasks'), )` and it doesn't specify the exchange at all, unlike normal `CELERY_QUEUES = (Queue(name, exchange, routing_key), )` in examples, you pointed to. I've been looking for `Broadcast` in API reference, but can't find it.

Comment: what I was saying is: I don't think you want to use a broadcast queue at all. I think you want to define a normal Celery queue on top of `Exchange('fanout')` exchange type

Comment: @Anentropic Well, I came to the same conclusion. :) Thanks, Anentropic, let this Broadcast queue be a mistery of Celery, whatever it is.

Comment: Hi @BorisBurkov, I'm trying to get celery working with rabbitmq fanout queues. This seems to be tricky, celery seems to be having lots of automation done that is not clear to me. Did you manage to get your celery workers consuming tasks from your fanout queue on all hosts?

Comment: Hi @Greg0ry, I looked up my configs - no, I think, I'm using `direct` queue type everywhere. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @BorisBurkov. I found what my issue was, left comment under accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#exchanges-queues-and-routing-keys

It appears the 'queue' definition in Celery includes the exchange, so you can define a Celery queue on top of `Exchange('fanout')` exchange type, which will have an underlying implementation of multiple RabbitMQ queues.

In this case I would guess you don't want a 'broadcast' queue in the Celery config, unless you really want multiple workers processing the same task.

Comment: This is old answer and celery is now at 4.x so I'll leave my observation for others. First - it seems `Broadcast` queue was improved and you can define your queue like this: `Broadcast(name='queue_name', Exchange(name='queue_name', type='fanout')` - at least this made all my hosts within rabbitmq cluster to receive my broadcast task and I could define that queue within worker start arguments (`-Q:1 queue_name -c:1 1`). Also it helps if you remember to erase status of your rabbitmq cluster each time you test new queues configuration. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

Having looked at the code (it's in the `kombu.common` package, not `celery`) and tried it out, it seems to work like this:

- You define a `Broadcast` 'queue' named 'foo' in your celery config.
- This creates an `Exchange` named 'foo', and an `auto_delete` queue with a unique id (via `uuid`), and with the alias 'foo' (I don't think the alias is actually used anywhere, it's just there for reference because the queue's real name is randomly generated)
- The unique queue is bound to the 'foo' exchange

So, the class is named `Broadcast`, but it's really a uniquely named queue that is bound to a fanout exchange. Therefore when each worker is started, it creates its own unique queue and binds to the fanout exchange.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Celery 4.0.1+, and broadcast is not working for you, please check https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3934 and see clokep's solution, it restores the previous version of amqp.py and that works for me.

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.